# How can I use an icon with q-btn (vuejs, quasar as a plugin)

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, quasar-framework

I've been trying to make this work:

`<q-btn flat round  icon="logo-linkedin" />`

But it does not work at all!

Here's how it looks on ionicons:
`<ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>`

Despite having all possible imports in `quasar-user-options.js` file:

```
import "./styles/quasar.scss";
import "@quasar/extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css";
import "@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css";
import "@quasar/extras/material-icons-outlined/material-icons-outlined.css";
import "@quasar/extras/material-icons-round/material-icons-round.css";
import "@quasar/extras/material-icons-sharp/material-icons-sharp.css";
import "@quasar/extras/fontawesome-v5/fontawesome-v5.css";
import "@quasar/extras/ionicons-v4/ionicons-v4.css";
import "@quasar/extras/mdi-v4/mdi-v4.css";
import "@quasar/extras/eva-icons/eva-icons.css";

import { Notify } from "quasar";

export default {
  config: {},
  plugins: { Notify },
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thanks to the guys on Discord and Github discussions, this works now:

```
import "./styles/quasar.scss";
import iconSet from "quasar/icon-set/ionicons-v4";
import "@quasar/extras/ionicons-v4/ionicons-v4.css";

import { Notify } from "quasar";

export default {
  config: {
    iconSet,
  },
  plugins: { Notify },
};
```

then:

```
<q-btn flat round icon="ion-logo-linkedin" />
```